# Appending a "0" to the front of a string

Tags: mysql

Someone in my company downloaded some data, played with it in Excel and uploaded again.

Excel when trying to be helpful truncated a leading zero on a file called `license_number`.

As a result rather than having "037463524" the data now says "37463524"

I know that if the string is eight characters long, I need to add a "0" to the front of it to correct the mess.

Is there a SQL query that I can run in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length)

```
UPDATE Tablename SET license_number = '0' + license_number WHERE LENGTH(license_number) = 8
```

or

```
UPDATE Tablename SET license_number = CONCAT('0', license_number) WHERE LENGTH(license_number) = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way by using [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET `Lic_NO` = LPAD(`Lic_NO`, 9, '0')
```